# Javascript Program Freezes and Causes Page to Refresh When Proccessing Large Amounts of Text

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

Alright so I am very new to JavaScript and Stack Overflow. I am still in high school but I have been working with Java and a few other languages for a while. Please give me any feedback that you can.

So I have recently started learning JavaScript and I was doing a project where you give the program text like an article or something and then give it key words and it return areas in the text where those words were mentioned. I already built this in java but I wanted to make it web based and have gotten pretty far but am having a problem with loading time. Essentially when I run this with a large amount of text it freezes for a while then eventually just refreshed the page and clears the data from the text field. Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <textarea id="input" rows="8" cols="100" ></textarea><br/>
  <textarea id="keywords" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea><br/>
  <textarea id="output" rows="8" cols="100"></textarea><br/>
  <button id="read">READ!</button><br />


  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('read').onclick = function(event) {
      var input = document.getElementById('input').value.split(" ");
      var keywords = document.getElementById('keywords').value.split(" ");
      var found = ""; 

      alert(input.length + "  " + keywords.length);
      for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++){
          if(input[i].toLowerCase().includes(keywords[j].toLowerCase())){
            if(i >= 25 && input.length >= i + 40){
              for(a = i- 25; a <= a + 40; a++){
                found = found + input[a];
              }
            }else{
              var length = input.length - i;
              for(a = 0; a < length; a++){
                found = found + input[a];
              }
            }
            found += "\n\n";
          }
        }
      }
      output.value = found;
    }
  </script>


</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop

```
for(a = i- 25; a <= a + 40; a++){
  outputs.push(input[a]);
}
```

is an infinite loop. `a` will always be smaller than `a + 40`. You probably wanted to say `i + 40`. But then your selection of output words is still strange, if not to say buggy. Assume your input is 10 words and you have a match in the 7th word. Then your program outputs the first 3 words - which doesn't include the match itself. You probably want to print x words before and y words after the match, but only if there are enough words to choose from. To this end, you could use the minimum and maximum function (see code below).

Some other things that become important when you want to improve the performance for larger texts are:

1. Whenever you concatenate a string with +=, a new object at a new
   memory address is created, which is bad. Store the words you want to
   output in an array and join them at the end with `join()`.
2. You call `toLowerCase()` multiple times on the same string. If you have enough storage space, store the lowercase version of each word and reuse them.

In the code below, I have fixed these issues. The result is in no way meant to be optimal.

```
document.getElementById('read').onclick = function(event) {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value.split(" ");
  var inputLower = new Array(input.length);

  var keywords = document.getElementById('keywords').value.split(" ");

  // create output array
  var outputs = new Array();
  // create arrays with lowercase words
  for (var k = 0; k < input.length; k++) {
    inputLower.push(input[k].toLowerCase());
  }
  var keywordsLower = new Array(keywords.length);
  for (var k = 0; k < keywords.length; k++) {
    keywordsLower.push(keywords[k].toLowerCase());
  }
  alert(input.length + "  " + keywords.length);
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
      if(inputLower[i].includes(keywordsLower[j])) {
        for (k = Math.max(i - 10, 0); k <= Math.min(i + 10, input.length - 1); k++) {
            // add at most 10 words before and 10 words after the matched word to the output
            outputs.push(input[k]);
        }
        outputs.push("\n\n");
      }
    }
  }
  // join the words of the output with a space
  output.value = outputs.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is super helpful. It was as simple as the a instead of I. And thank you for all the other information too I am very new to javascript and this is very appreciated.